# Construct slide deck from screenshots of slides

Tags: windows, note-taking, slideshow

When attending remote meetings where the interlocutor presents slides, I sometimes would like to take a screenshot of each slide they show and save it as an easily browsable slide deck on my side. What program or or web-based service allows to do so?

---

Programs I tried along with their limitations:

- Microsoft PowerPoint: I need to zoom out to view the entire screenshot and I need to click on add new slide for each new screenshot.
- Microsoft Paint: I need to save each screenshots as an independent file.
- Google Document: I could paste screenshots as images in a landscape document, but it's not very convenient to browse the document and a bit lossy in terms of image quality.

---

- Operating system: Microsoft Windows or web-based service
- License: any
- Price: any

Answer (score 1):

A screen capture program such as [SnagIt](https://www.techsmith.com/screen-capture.html) can be configured to capture a specific area of the screen (user defined) and save it to a user-defined folder, while prepending a user-defined filename with advancing numerical components. The default hot key for SnagIt is the print-screen key but nearly any combination can be used.

The program runs on Windows and also provides for a free trial. I've used SnagIt for uncounted years and have not found any task for which is is not a capable piece of software.